# Test if executable exists in Python?

Tags: python, path

In Python, is there a portable and simple way to test if an executable program exists?

By simple I mean something like the `which` command which would be just perfect. I don't want to search PATH manually or something involving trying to execute it with `Popen` & al and see if it fails (that's what I'm doing now, but imagine it's `launchmissiles`)

Comment: What's wrong with searching the PATH environment variable? What do you think the UNIX 'which' command does?

Comment: Is which.py script from stdlib a simple way?

Comment: @J.F. - the which.py script incl. with Python depends on 'ls' and some of the other comments indicate that Piotr was looking for a cross-platform answer.

Comment: @Jay: Thanks for the comment. I has coreutils installed on Windows so I didn't notice that which.py is unix-specific.

Comment: There is also `which`, the third-party module: http://code.activestate.com/pypm/which/

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646955/how-to-tell-whether-a-file-is-executable-on-windows-in-python/1738907#1738907 The question is about Windows but the code works on Posix too

Comment: Keep in mind that  os.access() does consider Windows ACLs only in Python 3.5 or later (see https://bugs.python.org/issue2528).

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/13936916/145400 should be the accepted answer in 2020? :)

Answer (score 337, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of:

```
def which(program):
    import os
    def is_exe(fpath):
        return os.path.isfile(fpath) and os.access(fpath, os.X_OK)

    fpath, fname = os.path.split(program)
    if fpath:
        if is_exe(program):
            return program
    else:
        for path in os.environ.get("PATH", "").split(os.pathsep):
            exe_file = os.path.join(path, program)
            if is_exe(exe_file):
                return exe_file

    return None
```

**Edit**: Updated code sample to include logic for handling case where provided argument is already a full path to the executable, i.e. "which /bin/ls". This mimics the behavior of the UNIX 'which' command.

**Edit**: Updated to use os.path.isfile() instead of os.path.exists() per comments.

**Edit**: `path.strip('"')` seems like the wrong thing to do here. Neither Windows nor POSIX appear to encourage quoted PATH items.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I accept your answer, though for me it answers my question by the negative. No such function exists in the libs, I just have to write it (I admit my formulation was not clear enough in the fact that I know what which does).

Comment: Jay, if you complete your answer according to mine (to have complete 'w') so I can remove mine.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, gotcha now.

Comment: @Piotr - updated the code for cases with full paths provided as argument

Comment: For some OS's you may need to add the executable's extension. For example, on Ubuntu I can write which("scp") but on Windows, I needed to write which("scp.exe").

Comment: I'd suggest changing "os.path.exists" to "os.path.isfile". Otherwise in Unix this might falsely match a directory with the +x bit set. I also find it useful to add this to the top of the function: import sys; if sys.platform == "win32" and not program.endswith(".exe"): program += ".exe". This way under Windows you can refer to either "calc" or "calc.exe", just like you could in a cmd window.

Comment: @KevinIvarsen A better option would be looping through the values of the `PATHEXT` env var because `command` is as valid as `command.com` as is `script` vs `script.bat`

Comment: You could re-write is_exec as `is_exec = lambda x: os.path.isfile(x) and os.access(x, os.X_OK)`.  Why?  just because I like lambda.

Comment: bash also expands tildes in path elements; use os.path.expanduser to recreate this.

Comment: Won't `os.access(x, os.X_OK)` return `True` for pretty much anything on Windows? (Added: [see here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/577007-need-simple-way-determine-if-file-executable) for discussion of this.)

Comment: isnt os.access(x, os.X_OK) enough?

Comment: @ealeon On Unix like systems both files and directories may have the X flag set. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened

Comment: Be careful (as always) on windows. os.access(f, os.X_OK) will return true for a text file which is the same behaviour as the where program. A more reliable way is to check if the file exists and if its extension matches one of the entries in the PATHEXT environment variable.

Comment: For Windows the solution should include searching the App Paths registry entry as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044937/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-path-of-an-application-with-standard-libraries, as these applications can also be found without including them in the PATH variable. shutils.which() doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: I'm new to python, so sorry if this is obvious, but why is `fpath` being defined and checked with `if fpath` at the beginning, it looks like it will just be false and skipped over? does the response from `split` get put into fpath and fname?

Comment: aaaah never mind, I understand now, `os.path.split` does works it out, very fancy, this pythong stuff is great, thanks

Comment: If someone wonders about the App Paths registry not working: this does not work from `cmd`, it does work from `ps`, but only with `Diagnostics.Process` and `Start-Process`.

Comment: Thank you for this; you're a scholar and a gentleman.

Answer (score 383):

I know this is an ancient question, but you can use `distutils.spawn.find_executable`.  This has  been [documented since python 2.4](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/dist/module-distutils.spawn.html) and has existed since python 1.6.

```
import distutils.spawn
distutils.spawn.find_executable("notepad.exe")
```

Also, Python 3.3 now offers [`shutil.which()`](https://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.which).

Comment: On `win32`, the `distutils.spawn.find_executable` implementation only looks for `.exe` rather than using the list of extensions to search for set in `%PATHEXT%`.  That's not great, but it might work for the all the cases someone needs.

Comment: example usage: `from distutils import spawn` `php_path = spawn.find_executable("php")`

Comment: Apparently `distutils.spawn` isn't available reliably: with my System install (/usr/bin/python) of Python 2.7.6 on OS X 10.10, I get: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spawn'` , although strangely it works on the same machine with the same version of Python, but from a virtualenv install.

Comment: @JoshKupershmidt, make sure to `import distutils.spawn`, or follow the `from distutils import spawn` syntax rather than just `import distutils`. Otherwise it may not be accessible and you will get the above `AttributeError` even if it is there.

Comment: For the record: the "Python 3.3 now offers shutil.which()" was rather brutally copy/pasted without attribution on Jan 27, 2013 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13936916/145400.

Comment: Since Python 3.10 the distutils package is deprecated. It will be removed in Python 3.12.

Comment: The distutils.spawn.find_executable function can find an executable based on such a path: "./executable_name", the other one cannot.

Answer (score 264):

Use **[shutil.which()](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/shutil.html#shutil.which)** from Python's wonderful standard library.

Documented as

> Return the path to an executable which would be run if the given cmd was called. **If no cmd would be called, return `None`**.

```py
import shutil

path = shutil.which("foo") 

if path is None:
    print("no executable found for command 'foo'")
else:
    print(f"path to executable 'foo': {path}")
```

Benefits over home-cooked solutions: documentation, interface stability, long-term maintenance. I advocated for this solution here ~10 years ago, and just one month ago (April 2023), a few relevant details improved again [under the hood](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/103179) of this high-level interface provided by excellent engineers doing the hard work for you. Batteries included !

By the way, the name is indeed derived from the famous `which` command on Unix-like systems (and the pedantic POSIX person says: "never use `which cmd`, use `command -v cmd`, it's more portable") :-).

Comment: By the way, this answer was the first one in this thread to suggest using `shutil.which()` if that matters to you ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: For interactive use, zsh has `where` which lists all matching executables in the path, not just the first one, and also includes shell functions and aliases in the search.  Yes, yes, pedantic zsh user, I know. :-)

Comment: Probably the best solution if you have 3.3 or later. I need to support an older version of Python (I know, I know), so going with Jay's solution.

Answer (score 81):

#### For python 3.3 and later:

```
import shutil

command = 'ls'
shutil.which(command) is not None
```

As a one-liner of [Jan-Philip Gehrcke Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13936916/1695680):

```
cmd_exists = lambda x: shutil.which(x) is not None
```

As a def:

```
def cmd_exists(cmd):
    return shutil.which(cmd) is not None
```

---

#### For python 3.2 and earlier:

```py
my_command = 'ls'
any(
    (
        os.access(os.path.join(path, my_command), os.X_OK) 
        and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, my_command)
    )
    for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep)
)
```

This is a one-liner of [Jay's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/377028/1695680), Also here as a lambda func:

```py
cmd_exists = lambda x: any((os.access(os.path.join(path, x), os.X_OK) and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))) for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep))
cmd_exists('ls')
```

Or lastly, indented as a function:

```py
def cmd_exists(cmd, path=None):
    """ test if path contains an executable file with name
    """
    if path is None:
        path = os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep)

    for prefix in path:
        filename = os.path.join(prefix, cmd)
        executable = os.access(filename, os.X_OK)
        is_not_directory = os.path.isfile(filename)
        if executable and is_not_directory:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: the "indented as a function" version uses the variable `x` where it should be `cmd`

Comment: you must also add a test to see if `os.path.join(path, cmd)` is a file, no? Afterall, directories can also have the executable bit set...

Comment: @MestreLion That does sound like a possible case, would you mind confirming this behavior and updating this answer? I am happy to change this post to a community wiki if that helps.

Comment: @ThorSummoner: I've confirmed it, and it does indeed require the test for file. A simple test: `mkdir -p -- "$HOME"/bin/dummy && PATH="$PATH":"$HOME"/bin && python -c 'import os; print any(os.access(os.path.join(path, "dummy"), os.X_OK) for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep))' && rmdir -- "$HOME"/bin/dummy`

Comment: Adding a simple `and os.path.isfile(...)` to the appropriate places is enough to fix that

Answer (score 21):

Just remember to specify the file extension on windows. Otherwise, you have to write a much complicated `is_exe` for windows using `PATHEXT` environment variable. You may just want to use [FindPath](http://www.raboof.com/projects/findpath/).

OTOH, why are you even bothering to search for the executable? The operating system will do it for you as part of `popen` call & will raise an exception if the executable is not found. All you need to do is catch the correct exception for given OS. Note that on Windows, `subprocess.Popen(exe, shell=True)` will fail silently if `exe` is not found.

---

Incorporating `PATHEXT` into the above implementation of `which` (in Jay's answer):

```
def which(program):
    def is_exe(fpath):
        return os.path.exists(fpath) and os.access(fpath, os.X_OK) and os.path.isfile(fpath)

    def ext_candidates(fpath):
        yield fpath
        for ext in os.environ.get("PATHEXT", "").split(os.pathsep):
            yield fpath + ext

    fpath, fname = os.path.split(program)
    if fpath:
        if is_exe(program):
            return program
    else:
        for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
            exe_file = os.path.join(path, program)
            for candidate in ext_candidates(exe_file):
                if is_exe(candidate):
                    return candidate

    return None
```

Comment: It fixed a bug in the accepted answer, feel this answer should be on top instead.

Comment: clever usage of `yield` in `ext_candidates`, gave me a better understanding of how that keyword works

Answer (score 14):

### For *nix platforms (Linux and OS X)

This seems to be working for me:

**Edited** to work on Linux, thanks to [Mestreion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624066/mestrelion)

```
def cmd_exists(cmd):
    return subprocess.call("type " + cmd, shell=True, 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) == 0
```

What we're doing here is using the builtin command `type` and checking the exit code. If there's no such command, `type` will exit with 1 (or a non-zero status code anyway).

The bit about stdout and stderr is just to silence the output of the `type` command, since we're only interested in the exit status code.

Example usage:

```
>>> cmd_exists("jsmin")
True
>>> cmd_exists("cssmin")
False
>>> cmd_exists("ls")
True
>>> cmd_exists("dir")
False
>>> cmd_exists("node")
True
>>> cmd_exists("steam")
False
```

Comment: I've tried it in Ubuntu 12.04, it throws `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Maybe in Mac `type` is an actual command

Comment: using `shell=True` is mandatory in Linux since `type` is a shell builtin there (I wonder why it isn't in Mac). But using it with user-supplied  arbitrary strings (such as `cmd`) is a major security risk, as pointed by the docs

Comment: cool, thanks for fixing it. I edited the answer to include your fix. In the future feel free to edit wrong answers yourself to make them more correct!

Comment: Good to know, thanks, but just FYI: this doesn't work on tcsh (6.17.00), because type is not a builtin in tcsh or csh. So it's not very universal.

Comment: Attention: be sure that the variable "cmd" contains valid data. If it comes from an external source, a bad guy could give you "ls; rm -rf /". I think the in-python solution (without subprocess) is much better. Next point: If you call this method often, the subprocess solution is much slower, since a lot of processes need to spawned.

Comment: Macs include a little wrapper as `/usr/bin/type` that basically just wraps the shell builtin.

Answer (score 10):

On the basis that it is [easier to ask forgiveness than permission](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) (and, importantly, that the command is safe to run) I would just try to use it and catch the error (OSError in this case - I checked for file does not exist and file is not executable and they both give OSError).

It helps if the executable has something like a `--version` or `--help` flag that is a quick no-op.

```
import subprocess
myexec = "python2.8"
try:
    subprocess.call([myexec, '--version']
except OSError:
    print "%s not found on path" % myexec
```

This is not a general solution, but will be the easiest way for a lot of use cases - those where the code needs to look for a single well known executable which is safe to run, or at least safe to run with a given flag.

Comment: It's too dangerous even to call `--version` on a program named `launchmissiles`!

Comment: +1, I like this approach. EAFP is a golden Python rule. Except perhaps for setting up UI, why would you want to know if `launchmissies` exists unless you want to launch missiles? Better to execute it and act upon exit status / exceptions

Comment: The problem with this method is that output is printed to the console. If you use pipes and shell=True, then the OSError never gets raised

Comment: On macOS you also have stub executables for e.g. `git` that you probably don't want to run blindly.

Comment: @MestreLion Well, you might want to just check that `launchmissiles` is really there so that you can `launchmissiles` immediately when needed later on, rather than faff about trying to figure out how to install `launchmissiles` during an emergency.

Answer (score 7):

See [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) module for some useful functions on pathnames. To check if an existing file is executable, use [os.access(path, mode)](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.access), with the os.X_OK mode.

> os.X_OK
>
> Value to include in the mode parameter of access() to determine if path can be executed.

**EDIT:** The suggested `which()` implementations are missing one clue - using [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build full file names.

Comment: Thanks, gimel, so basically I have my answer: no such function exists, I must do It manually.

Comment: Don't use os.access.  access function is designed for suid programs.

Answer (score 5):

I know that I'm being a bit of a necromancer here, but I stumbled across this question and the accepted solution didn't work for me for all cases Thought it might be useful to submit anyway. In particular, the "executable" mode detection, and the requirement of supplying the file extension. Furthermore, both python3.3's `shutil.which` (uses `PATHEXT`) and python2.4+'s `distutils.spawn.find_executable` (just tries adding `'.exe'`) only work in a subset of cases.

So I wrote a "super" version (based on the accepted answer, and the `PATHEXT` suggestion from Suraj). This version of `which` does the task a bit more thoroughly, and tries a series of "broadphase" breadth-first techniques first, and eventually tries more fine-grained searches over the `PATH` space:

```
import os
import sys
import stat
import tempfile


def is_case_sensitive_filesystem():
    tmphandle, tmppath = tempfile.mkstemp()
    is_insensitive = os.path.exists(tmppath.upper())
    os.close(tmphandle)
    os.remove(tmppath)
    return not is_insensitive

_IS_CASE_SENSITIVE_FILESYSTEM = is_case_sensitive_filesystem()


def which(program, case_sensitive=_IS_CASE_SENSITIVE_FILESYSTEM):
    """ Simulates unix `which` command. Returns absolute path if program found """
    def is_exe(fpath):
        """ Return true if fpath is a file we have access to that is executable """
        accessmode = os.F_OK | os.X_OK
        if os.path.exists(fpath) and os.access(fpath, accessmode) and not os.path.isdir(fpath):
            filemode = os.stat(fpath).st_mode
            ret = bool(filemode & stat.S_IXUSR or filemode & stat.S_IXGRP or filemode & stat.S_IXOTH)
            return ret

    def list_file_exts(directory, search_filename=None, ignore_case=True):
        """ Return list of (filename, extension) tuples which match the search_filename"""
        if ignore_case:
            search_filename = search_filename.lower()
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for f in files:
                filename, extension = os.path.splitext(f)
                if ignore_case:
                    filename = filename.lower()
                if not search_filename or filename == search_filename:
                    yield (filename, extension)
            break

    fpath, fname = os.path.split(program)

    # is a path: try direct program path
    if fpath:
        if is_exe(program):
            return program
    elif "win" in sys.platform:
        # isnt a path: try fname in current directory on windows
        if is_exe(fname):
            return program

    paths = [path.strip('"') for path in os.environ.get("PATH", "").split(os.pathsep)]
    exe_exts = [ext for ext in os.environ.get("PATHEXT", "").split(os.pathsep)]
    if not case_sensitive:
        exe_exts = map(str.lower, exe_exts)

    # try append program path per directory
    for path in paths:
        exe_file = os.path.join(path, program)
        if is_exe(exe_file):
            return exe_file

    # try with known executable extensions per program path per directory
    for path in paths:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, program)
        for extension in exe_exts:
            exe_file = filepath+extension
            if is_exe(exe_file):
                return exe_file

    # try search program name with "soft" extension search
    if len(os.path.splitext(fname)[1]) == 0:
        for path in paths:
            file_exts = list_file_exts(path, fname, not case_sensitive)
            for file_ext in file_exts:
                filename = "".join(file_ext)
                exe_file = os.path.join(path, filename)
                if is_exe(exe_file):
                    return exe_file

    return None
```

Usage looks like this:

```
>>> which.which("meld")
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Meld\\meld\\meld.exe'
```

The accepted solution did not work for me in this case, since there were files like `meld.1`, `meld.ico`, `meld.doap`, etc also in the directory, one of which were returned instead (presumably since lexicographically first) because the executable test in the accepted answer was incomplete and giving false positives.

Comment: plenty of opportunity for a mounted drive to be case insensitive - even if the /tmp isn't.   and writing a file is not a good mechanism...  instead LS the root of each path member...  then check to see if a known entry exists with a different, missing case.   now even for a read-only mounted network drive (common for shipping software), this works!

Answer (score 2):

This seems simple enough and works both in python 2 and 3

```
try: subprocess.check_output('which executable',shell=True)
except: sys.exit('ERROR: executable not found')
```

Comment: Sorry Jaap, but this solution only works when the executable doesn't call an exit code 1 if it's called incorrectly. So, for example, it'll work for "dir" and "ls", but if you execute against something that requires configuration it'll break even though the executable is there.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "require configuration"? By itself 'which' doesn't actually execute anything but just checks the PATH for existence of an executable by this name (man which).

Comment: Ohh, so you are using "which" in order to find the executable. So this only works for Linux/Unix?

Comment: Use `command -v executable` or `type executable` to be universal. There are cases where which on Macs does not return expected results.

Answer (score 2):

Added windows support

```
def which(program):
    path_ext = [""];
    ext_list = None

    if sys.platform == "win32":
        ext_list = [ext.lower() for ext in os.environ["PATHEXT"].split(";")]

    def is_exe(fpath):
        exe = os.path.isfile(fpath) and os.access(fpath, os.X_OK)
        # search for executable under windows
        if not exe:
            if ext_list:
                for ext in ext_list:
                    exe_path = "%s%s" % (fpath,ext)
                    if os.path.isfile(exe_path) and os.access(exe_path, os.X_OK):
                        path_ext[0] = ext
                        return True
                return False
        return exe

    fpath, fname = os.path.split(program)

    if fpath:
        if is_exe(program):
            return "%s%s" % (program, path_ext[0])
    else:
        for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
            path = path.strip('"')
            exe_file = os.path.join(path, program)
            if is_exe(exe_file):
                return "%s%s" % (exe_file, path_ext[0])
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

An important question is "**Why** do you need to test if executable exist?" Maybe you don't? ;-)

Recently I needed this functionality to launch viewer for PNG file. I wanted to iterate over some predefined viewers and run the first that exists. Fortunately, I came across `os.startfile`. It's much better! Simple, portable and uses the *default* viewer on the system:

```
>>> os.startfile('yourfile.png')
```

**Update:** I was wrong about `os.startfile` being portable... It's Windows only. On Mac you have to run `open` command. And `xdg_open` on Unix. There's a [Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue3177) on adding Mac and Unix support for `os.startfile`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the external lib called "sh" (http://amoffat.github.io/sh/).

```
import sh
print sh.which('ls')  # prints '/bin/ls' depending on your setup
print sh.which('xxx') # prints None
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [which.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/which.py?view=markup) script in a standard Python distribution (e.g. on Windows `'\PythonXX\Tools\Scripts\which.py'`).

EDIT: `which.py` depends on `ls` therefore it is not cross-platform.

Answer (score -1):

So basically you want to find a file in mounted filesystem (not necessarily in PATH directories only) and check if it is executable. This translates to following plan:

- enumerate all files in locally mounted filesystems
- match results with name pattern
- for each file found check if it is executable

I'd say, doing this in a portable way will require lots of computing power and time. Is it really what you need?