# How can I find the path for an executable?

Tags: python

I need to setup environment with the path to a binary. In the shell, I can use `which` to find the path. Is there an equivalent in python?
This is my code.

```py
cmd = ["which","abc"]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res = p.stdout.readlines()
if len(res) == 0: return False
return True
```

Comment: Even in the shell itself, `which` itself is not a good choice for detecting if a command is installed. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/677212#677212)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if executable exists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377017/test-if-executable-exists-in-python)

Comment: Not sure if it's applicable but take a look at `import sys; sys.executable`.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

There is [`distutils.spawn.find_executable()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.spawn).

Comment: +1, this is cool and part of the standard library! Be aware that it's very limited on Windows - it doesn't parse PATHEXT, instead it assumes it should be searching for a '.exe' extension (missing batch files etc)

Comment: Beware it doesn't check whether file is executable.

Comment: This didn't work for me on 2.7 or 3.6. It gave an error that the spawn module wasn't found.

Comment: @temoto And yet despite that it won't find a dll file (that I can check is on `PATH` via `where.exe`) for me on Windows.

Comment: @GreenMatt, just tried in on 3.7, works just fine. As mentioned by others, don't forget to run `import distutils.spawn` first.

Comment: There is a huge bug in this function in that if there is a file in the current directory with the same name as the executable you're searching for, it returns the bare executable name ([see this source line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/spawn.py#L101)).
As an example, if you run the following:
`$ touch bash; python3 -c "from distutils.spawn import find_executable; print(find_executable('bash'))"` it prints out `bash`. Use `shutil.which` instead.

Answer (score 97):

I know this is an older question, but if you happen to be using Python 3.3+ you can use `shutil.which(cmd)`. You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html?highlight=.which#shutil.which). It has the advantage of being in the standard library.

An example would be like so:

```
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.which("bash")
'/usr/bin/bash'
```

Answer (score 14):

There's not a command to do that, but you can iterate over `environ["PATH"]` and look if the file exists, which is actually what `which` does.

```
import os

def which(file):
    for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, file)):
                return os.path.join(path, file)

    return None
```

Good luck!

Comment: You want to be cautious making assumptions about the pathsep character.

Comment: and path separator, but this is just a quirk to make a point. Good luck!

Comment: use `os.path.sep` instead of `/` and `os.pathsep` instead of `:`

Comment: Do not use '+', use os.path.join. See more up-voted answers for a stdlib implementation (distutils) and a more platform-independent from the Twisted project.

Comment: thanks for os.path.join. The twisted implementation is completely isolated, doesn't seem to have any inter-dependency with the rest of the project, so as an implementation it is much better (than mine at least)

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like the following:

```
import os
import os.path
def which(filename):
    """docstring for which"""
    locations = os.environ.get("PATH").split(os.pathsep)
    candidates = []
    for location in locations:
        candidate = os.path.join(location, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(candidate):
            candidates.append(candidate)
    return candidates
```

Comment: You need to take `PATHEXT` into account as well

Comment: On a Windows machine I suspect that you would likely look for the exact name of the file, as opposed to assuming the extensions. With that being said it wouldn't be hard to add an inner loop that iterates over the members of PATHEXT.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `shell=True`, then your command will be run through the system shell, which will automatically find the binary on the path:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("abc", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: Even without `shell=True` it is looked up in path, but it does not help if you want to find which of the possible commands exists.

Answer (score 3):

This is the equivalent of the which command, which not only checks if the file exists, but also whether it is executable:

```
import os

def which(file_name):
    for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
        full_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
        if os.path.exists(full_path) and os.access(full_path, os.X_OK):
            return full_path
    return None
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a one-line version of earlier answers:

```
import os
which = lambda y: next(filter(lambda x: os.path.isfile(x) and os.access(x,os.X_OK),[x+os.path.sep+y for x in os.getenv("PATH").split(os.pathsep)]),None)
```

used like so:

```
>>> which("ls")
'/bin/ls'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Python2, `TypeError: list object is not an iterator`.