# Getting return value from `which` to test for existence of a directory

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm trying to write something that will test for bower being installed on a computer. I'm trying to do it in either python or shell scripting. I'm okay with either, but failing with both. I'm using the `which` function and execute it via subprocess in python. (Maybe there's another way to do it that is pure python, not having it execute bash(?))

### Python:

```
 if subprocess.call(['which', 'bower']):
    print("bower exists at: " + subprocess.call(['which', 'bower']))
else:
    print("no bower") //this prints
```

### Bash:

```
if [ which bower ] #also tried if [ which bower == /usr/local/bin/bower]
then
    echo "bower installed"
else
    echo "no bower"
fi
```

I guess the problem is that `which` is not returning a string, it just prints it. How can I access the information it returns?

Comment: Python: Use `subprocess.check_output()`.  Bash: Use [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst).

Comment: You may want to have a look at ['which' equivalent function in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226958/which-equivalent-function-in-python)

Comment: You should also probably read up on why [`which` is not a good choice for detecting if a program is installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/677212#677212).

Comment: "just prints" and "returns" are the same thing in the shell in most cases. The problem with the shell snippet is that you don't want the wrapping `[`/`]` for that. You want to test the **return code** of `which` (actually you don't want to use `which` at all see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script) for more on that).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `find_executable` function from `distutils`. It will return `None` if the executable is not found:

```
>>> from distutils.spawn import find_executable
>>> find_executable('man')
'/usr/bin/man'
>>> find_executable('noman')
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -x "$(which bower)" ]]; then
  echo "bower installed"
else
  echo "no bower"
fi
```

`-x` indicates that the file exists and executable by you, so if the file is not executable by you then it will show "no bower" although it might be installed.

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
if type bower &>/dev/null
then
    echo "bower installed"
else
    echo "no bower"
fi
```

In bash, `type` uses `bash` itself to determine whether `bower` can be found.  By default, `type` is able to find aliases and functions.   If you only want to report success if the command is an actual physical file on the system, use the `-p` option to `type`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, use [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> result=subprocess.check_output(['command', '-v', 'python'])
```

Also, don't use `which`. Use `command -v program_name` You also need to catch errors rather than just check truthiness.

So your snippet becomes:

```
import subprocess

try:
    result=subprocess.check_output(['command', '-v', 'bower'])
    print("bower exists at: %s" % result)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print("no bower")
```