# Find path of linux system binary from within python

Tags: python, linux, bash, path, subprocess

Is there a way to find the path to any given system binary from within Python, similar to the bash command `which`?

I know I could use the `subprocess` or `sh` modules, but these either require me to launch a new process or install additional packages.

Is there a simple pythonic way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226958/which-equivalent-function-in-python) might be of use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [distutils.spawn.find_executable](http://nullege.com/codes/search/distutils.spawn.find_executable), it tries to find *executable* in the directories listed in *path*.