# How to check for clang presence in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I check that `clang` is built or that `clang` tool is available?

I need to check it in Python 2.7.

I tried with `os.path.exists(file_path)`, but you can build `clang` anywhere so it is not the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you if `clang` is available in the path, it performs a search for the presence of the `clang` executable:

```
from distutils.spawn import find_executable

clang_executable = find_executable('clang')
```

If it finds `clang` it will return the path to the executable, e.g. `/usr/bin/clang`, otherwise it will return `None`.

[This](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.spawn) is the relevant part of the docs (not that descriptive), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226958/which-equivalent-function-in-python) is a SO question looking for something similar.

Comment: This is works, thanks. I'm looking for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could install gnu `which`: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/which.htm

Add `which` to your `PATH`, and then run:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output("which clang")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Unix/Linux and clang is on your PATH:

```
import subprocess
c = subprocess.call(["which", "clang"])
if c == 0:
    print("clang is available")
```