# Bash script to pythonscript Convertion

Tags: python, bash, git, python-2.7, shell

BASH CODE:

```
source /proj/common/tools/repo/etc/profile.d/repo.sh
repo project init $branch
repo project sync
source poky/fnc-init-build-env build
bitbake -g $image
```

I converted this bash code into python(**version 2.7**). While executing my python code, I am getting ***repo command not found***  message.

PYTHON CODE:

```
os.system("source /proj/common/tools/repo/etc/profile.d/repo.sh")
os.system("repo project init " + branch)
os.system("repo project sync")
os.system("source poky/fnc-init-build-env build")
os.chdir("poky/build")
os.system("bitbake -g " + image)
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
sh: repo: command not found
sh: repo: command not found
```

I tried with subprocess.call(), I am getting the same error message.

Comment: Each `os.system` call invokes a unique shell. The `os.system("source ...` command had no effect on the next shell used with `os.system(" repo ...`. Generally, you won't have luck here unless you reimplement `repo.sh` also.

Comment: Aside from the subshell problem, what is the point of this? If it's an exercise I'm afraid you have misunderstood. Converting to a Python script would involve zero invocations of `os.system` with the original source code, unless absolutely necessary. As in, no library exists to do this in Python, and writing one would be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: i tried with subprocess.


subprocess.call(["source /proj/common/tools/repo/etc/profile.d/repo.sh", "repo project init " + branch, "repo project sync","source poky/fnc-init-build-env build","bitbake -g " + image], shell=True).

It shows same error message

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this call:

```
os.system("source /proj/common/tools/repo/etc/profile.d/repo.sh")
```

The problem is that it runs `source` in a separate subshell and when the subshell exits all changes to the environment (`cd` commands if there are any and environment variables, most notable `PATH`) are gone.

My advice is to continue using the shell script you've used — just call it from Python with one `os.system()` call. Inside the shell script you can use `source`.

Comment: When i execute the same command in python interactive mode, sometimes it is working. Sometimes it is not working.

I don't know why.

Comment: Depends on the value of `PATH` that you've sent before starting Python.

Comment: when i execute "source poky/fnc-init-build-env build" in bash , directory will changed inside poky build (.i.e./data/users/dependencies/Lseries/poky/build).
But when i execute in python,directory is not going inside poky/build.

Answer (score 0):

You could at least use the full path for the repo command.

That would avoid the subshell to have to know where the repo command is (meaning have the right `PATH` set on each `os.system` call).

Comment: Can i know how to use that

Comment: In your regular shell, do `which repo`: that will give you the full path to use.

Comment: is there any way to perform this functionality using python code

Comment: @sabarishs a `which` equivalent done in python would be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15133367/6309

Comment: Now i am getting error , when i execute " os.system("bitbake -g fss-image-full-l100")" . Because , directory is not going inside " poky/build".

Please help me in solving this

Comment: @sabarishs Can you test `os.system("pwd")` after `os.chdir("poky/build")`?

Comment: I tried os.chdir("poky/build"), still i am getting "bitbake command not found" error