# How can I find a file on the main OS/System PATH (not the PythonPath)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pathlib

How can I find a file the location of a file on the System PATH (i.e. in Windows %PATH% environment variable) with Python?

This is not about the Python Path, the built-in `sys.path`, or the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, but the PATH from the main OS that is present in terminals such as CMD, bash, etc.

Preferences:

1. Direct Python code (rather than running a shell command)
2. A Python 3-based solution, using **`pathlib.Path`**
3. Platform-independent

### Notes

1. I'm not looking to just get the PATH (that is just `os.environ['PATH']`), but a solution to find a particular file on the PATH, similar to the Windows `where` command, or linux `which` command, but using Python code.
2. I'm looking to find any file, not just executables (ideally you could put in a file pattern and get all results), different from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226958/how-can-i-find-the-path-for-an-executable).

Comment: On Linux it's the environment variable `PATH`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ.

Comment: I'm not looking to get the PATH, but find files on it. Will update the Q.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the path for an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226958/how-can-i-find-the-path-for-an-executable)

Comment: @safay That Q&A is focusing on executables, I'm looking for other patterns as well. It has good answers for exe's though (the `shutil.which` is good to know!). I'm also asking for pathlib.