# Opening a process with Popen and getting the PID

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm working on a nifty little function:

```
def startProcess(name, path):
    """
    Starts a process in the background and writes a PID file

    returns integer: pid
    """

    # Check if the process is already running
    status, pid = processStatus(name)

    if status == RUNNING:
        raise AlreadyStartedError(pid)

    # Start process
    process = subprocess.Popen(path + ' > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &', shell=True)

    # Write PID file
    pidfilename = os.path.join(PIDPATH, name + '.pid')
    pidfile = open(pidfilename, 'w')
    pidfile.write(str(process.pid))
    pidfile.close()

    return process.pid
```

The problem is that `process.pid` isn't the correct PID. It seems it's always 1 lower than the correct PID. For instance, it says the process started at 31729, but `ps` says it's running at 31730. Every time I've tried it's off by 1. I'm guessing the PID it returns is the PID of the **current** process, not the started one, and the new process gets the 'next' pid which is 1 higher. If this is the case, I can't just rely on returning `process.pid + 1` since I have no guarantee that it'll always be correct.

Why doesn't `process.pid` return the PID of the new process, and how can I achieve the behaviour I'm after?

Comment: Try removing `shell=True` and your `>` stuff.

Comment: i have the same problem and i found out the hard way, it's not always PID+1, it was at first, but now it's giving me +2

Comment: @Hubro I'd like to use this nifty function in some of my own code! Would you mind posting your code for `processStatus()`?

Comment: @Jordan It's been way too long, sorry. I have no idea what I was even writing this for.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From the documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html:

> Popen.pid The process ID of the child process.
>
> Note that if you set the shell argument to True, this is the process
> ID of the spawned shell.

If `shell` is false, it should behave as you expect, I think.

If you were relying on `shell` being `True` for resolving executable paths using the `PATH` environment variable, you can accomplish the same thing using [`shutil.which`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which) instead, then pass the absolute path to Popen instead. (As an aside, if you are using Python 3.5 or newer, you should be using [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) rather than Popen.

Comment: I needed `shell=True` for the relative path to python to work. I guess I'll replace it with the absolute path and set `shell` to false. Thanks for the information!

Comment: Passing the path through os.path.abspath first should fix that for you. http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html

Comment: Nah, running `os.path.abspath('python')` just returns my working directory plus 'python', e.g. '/root/python'

Comment: Ah I see, you were relying on the shell's PATH variable. Another trick you can use is executing `/usr/bin/env python` instead. I've seen it mostly used in shell scripts, but may help you here.

Comment: Ah yes, that would probably work, but wouldn't that cause the same issue? Wouldn't `pid` return the PID of `env`? Or does `env` perhaps use `exec`?

Comment: So I guess you really want to do $PATH resolution in Python then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377017/test-if-executable-exists-in-python has an answer that should work for that.

Comment: >> 
>>> import os
>>> import subprocess
>>> from subprocess import Popen
>>> import requests
>>> from time import sleep
>>> env = dict(os.environ)
>>> env['JAVA_OPTS'] = '8000 7'
>>> jarFile = '/Path to jar file/myfile.jar'
>>> process = subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', jarFile], env=env, shell=True)
>>> pid = Popen.pid

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    pid = Popen.pid
AttributeError: type object 'Popen' has no attribute 'pid'

Comment: SimonM: you need to get process.pid, not Popen.pid