# How to return a process id of a lengthy process started using Thread in python before the thread completes its execution

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

How can I return a process id of a lengthy process started using Thread in Python before the thread completes its execution?

1. I'm using Tkinter GUI so I can't start a lengthy process on the main thread so instead I start one on a separate thread.
2. The thread in turn calls `subprocess.popen`. This process should run for like 5 -6 hours.
3. But When I press stopbutton I need this process to stop but I am unable to return the process id of the process created using `subprocess.popen`.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Save the `pid` in `global var` so you are able to `signal` the `process` to terminate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening a process with Popen and getting the PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989922/opening-a-process-with-popen-and-getting-the-pid)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `subprocess.Popen` simply to spin off another process, there is no reason you need to do so from another thread. A sub-process created this way does not block your main thread. You can continue to do other things while the sub-process is running. You simply keep a reference to the `Popen` object returned.

The `Popen` object has all the facilities you need for monitoring / interacting with the sub-process. You can read and write to its standard input and output (via `stdin` and `stdout` members, if created with `PIPE`); you can monitor readability / writability of `stdin` and `stdout` (with `select` module); you can check whether the sub-process is still in existence with `poll`, reap its exit status with `wait`; you can stop it with `terminate` (or `kill` depending on how emphatic you wish to be).

There *are* certainly times when it might be advantageous to do this from another thread -- for example, if you need significant interaction with the sub-process and implementing that in the main thread would over-complicate your logic. In that case, it would be best to arrange a mechanism whereby you signal to your other "monitoring" thread that it's time to shutdown and allow the monitoring thread to execute `terminate` or `kill` on the sub-process.