# Determining if an application is installed with Sikuli Automation

Tags: sikuli

I would like to create a Sikuli script to determine if an application or software is installed in Mac, Linux, and Windows. How can I do this? If Sikuli is not convenient, please suggest the best possible way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No through Sikuli, but there are ways of searching for executables using jython.  The link below will get you started.

[Test if executable exists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377017/test-if-executable-exists-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Sikuli is not convenient, but if you have to use it, you can do it this way:

**Windows**

- Open the Control Panel and go to Add/Remove applications
- Scroll al the list and try to find() the icon of the application you're looking for

**OSX**

- Open the Finder and go to the Applications folder
- Scroll all the window and try to find() the icon of the application you're looking for

If finding the icon fails, try again finding by text `find("My Application Name")` as the vision engine is not 100% accurate, so it may fail even if the icon is displayed.

Comment: Note that another alternative if finding the icon fails is to set the match percentage to somewhere in the 90-95% range. By default Sikuli uses a 70% match. The tolerance can be changed by using the following `find(Pattern("image.png").similar(.95))`. Even at high match percentage, the vision engine can be unreliable, but its worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Spearson's answer is good if you're looking for command-line programs.  If you mean installed programs that aren't necessarily available from the command-line, I've used Sikuli to do this before.

**Windows**:
Click the Start Menu, type the application name, look for it to appear in the results

**Mac OS**:
Type `command-space` or click the Spotlight menu, search for the application name there

**Linux**:
Hardest, because there's no one desktop.  Most of them have something that works like the Windows Start Menu, though.

I like the solution because it's mostly the same between operating systems, but it's also fairly brittle.  Some failure cases are

- Windows is themed differently or the taskbar is in an unexpected location
- The program didn't install a Start Menu shortcut
- Spotlight hasn't indexed the application yet (because it was just installed)
- There's another version or program installed with the same name

Answer (score 0):

What I do to check if Notepad is installed is:

```
zen = App.open('Notepad')
if (zen != 'None'):
    print('Program is installed!')
    wait(2)
    # Close Notepad again. 
    App.close('Notepad')
else:
    print('Program is not installed!')
```

Or if you know the path where the file is installed:

```
import os
pathA = os.path.exists(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
print(pathA)
```