# detecting programs in python

Tags: python, linux, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test if executable exists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377017/test-if-executable-exists-in-python)

Is there a python function to let me detect whether a program is installed in the computer.  I have a program that runs an .exe, that part works on windows but to run it in linux you need wine so I need a way for the python function to detect wine.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which

Comment: The best way would be to query the package manager. Different distros have different ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `os.get_exec_path()` to get a list of directories which are set in `PATH` environment variable.  If the executable you are looking for is not present in any of these directories it is correct to assume that the program is not installed.

The code snipped to determine whether there is Wine installed then would look like this:

```
import os
winePath = None
for directory in os.get_exec_path():
    testWinePath = os.path.join(directory, "wine")
    if os.path.exists(testWinePath) and os.access(testWinePath, os.R_OK | os.X_OK):
        winePath = executablePath
        break
```

If there is Wine installed then the path to its executable file (`wine`) will be in `winePath` variable; if not found `winePath` will be `None`.
The code is also checking whether the file has correct perrmisions for reading and executing it.

The `os.get_exec_path()` is available since Python 3.2.  In older versions you can use `os.environ["PATH"].split(":")` instead.