# How can I use this bash test construct in Python?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have a bash snippet I would like to port over to Python. It finds where SVN is located and whether it is executable.

```
SVN=`which svn 2>&1` 
if [[ ! -x $SVN ]]; then
    echo "A subversion binary could not be found ($SVN)"        
fi
```

Here is my current attempt in Python using the subprocess module:

```
SVN = Popen('which svn 2>&1', shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
Popen("if [[ ! -x SVN ]]; then echo 'svn could not be found or executed'; fi", shell=True)
```

This does not work because while I do have the location of SVN saved in the local namespace of Python, I can't access it from Popen.

I also tried combining into one Popen object:

```
Popen("if [[ ! -x 'which svn 2>&1']]; then echo 'svn could not be found'; fi", shell=True)
```

But I get this error (and needless to say, looks very unwieldy)

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near `;'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `if [[ ! -x 'which svn 2>&1']]; then echo 'svn could not be found'; fi'
```

Is there a Python version of the test construct "-x"? I think that would be ideal. Other workarounds would be appreciated as well.

Thanks

Comment: [this site](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457094) provides a snippet that looks like `commands.getoutput("if [ -x myfile ]\nthen echo true\nfi")`. However this is hardly "porting to Python" since you're still invoking Bash.

Comment: `os.stat` can give you some information about a given file, such as its permissions, but I think you'd still need to build up a "executable for current user" test on top of that.

Comment: can you store the bash command as a string first, so that you can concatenate it with variable SVN? then pass that to Popen()...

Comment: Found it, the 'executable for current user' can be done using [`os.access`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SVN = Popen('which svn 2>&1', shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
str="if [[ ! -x " + SVN + " ]]; then echo 'svn could not be found or executed'; fi"
Popen(str, shell=True)
```

Comment: That's extremely inefficient, it forks a lot, and leaves zombie processes around.

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest solution:

```
path_to_svn = shutil.which('svn')
is_executable = os.access(path_to_svn, os.X_OK)
```

[`shutil.which`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html#shutil.which) is new in Python 3.3; there's a polyfill in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/377028/399317). You could grab the path from `Popen` too if you really want, but that's not necessary.

And here are the docs for [`os.access`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.access).

Comment: `os.access()` is redundant. `shutil.which()` already checks `X_OK` by default.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use which, you can already try to run svn without parameters and if it works it means it's there.

```
try:
    SVN = subprocess.Popen('svn')
    SVN.wait()
    print "svn exists"
except OSError:
    print "svn does not exist"
```