# Is there a way to find the path of an application with standard libraries?

Tags: python, windows, installation-path

I'd like to know if it is possible to find the installation directory of an application under Windows 7, such as MS Excel, with standard python 2.7 libraries. I mean, it shouldn't use any pywin32, or xlrd etc.

Maybe it will look up registry to find the installation path?

Comment: [_winreg](http://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\**\Common\InstallRoot` as key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be quite tricky, however one approach would be to search for the launcher exe location in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\foo.exe`

Thusly something like this (I do not have Windows on this computer, so edits are welcome if bugs found ;), code should be Python 2 and 3 compatible):

```
try:
    import winreg
except ImportError:
    import _winreg as winreg

handle = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe")

num_values = winreg.QueryInfoKey(handle)[1]
for i in range(num_values):
    print(winreg.EnumValue(handle, i))
```

On Python 2 the module is named `_winreg`, but `winreg` on Python 3.

Comment: great! how did you know?

Comment: googled for registry keys and then wrote some code based on the man pages

Comment: Sometimes the [`winreg.ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#winreg.ExpandEnvironmentStrings) might be useful, too. Great answer!