# General file open for Python which does not care about file compression

Tags: python, file-io

In my data analysis I usually have to handle all kinds of ascii files (with either space or comma separated values), and the large ones I regularly compress, especially if they end up in `svn`. Is there a way to write a `anyOpen()` function which figures out the zip status from the file name and opens it in appropriate way?

Comment: Latest version of the solution below can be found at https://github.com/DarkoVeberic/utl/tree/master/futile

Answer (score 3):

Yes. For example, place the example below in a file `util.py`. It implements a solution where you can simply open files (for reading or writing) as e.g. in

```
f1 = util.anyOpen('data.txt')
f2 = util.anyOpen('data.txt.gz')
f3 = util.anyOpen('data.txt.bz2')
f3 = util.anyOpen('data.txt.xz')
```

This comes very handy when the filename is read from the command-line. With `anyOpen()` you do not have to do any case handling, just pass the filename along,

```
with util.anyOpen(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

Furthermore, you can control where the unzipping is done: with `external=NORMAL` python libraries are used, and with `external=PROCESS` external `gzip`, `bzip2`, or `xz` process is used; with `external=PARALLEL`, the parallel versions `pigz` and `pbzip2` are used. If no external commands are found the function falls back to python libraries (not for `xz`, though).

The added feature is a simple way to open unix pipes by adding an exclamation sign as the first character of the `filename` argument (similar to the Mathematica syntax), i.e.

```
date = util.anyOpen('!date').readline()
```

or

```
ssv_data = util.anyOpen('!cat foo.csv | tr "," " "')
```

You might wonder why external processes for unzipping would be needed? There are several reasons: (1) nowadays almost every CPU has more then one core and the external unzipping process makes your Python code process the I/O with this file using the full core. The speedup is especially noticeable with the `.bz2` files since zip/unzip is quite slow. (2) Python's `gzip` and `bz` modules do not support unzipping of multiple-stream files created by `pigz` and `pbzip2`. (3) no Python support for `.xz` files.

```
NORMAL = 0    # use python zip libraries
PROCESS = 1   # use (zcat, gzip) or (bzcat, bzip2)
PARALLEL = 2  # (pigz -dc, pigz) or (pbzip2 -dc, pbzip2)

def anyOpen(filename, mode='r', buff=1024*1024, external=PARALLEL):
    if 'r' in mode and 'w' in mode:
        return None
    if filename.startswith('!'):
        import subprocess
        if 'r' in mode:
            return subprocess.Popen(filename[1:], shell=True, bufsize=buff,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
        elif 'w' in mode:
            return subprocess.Popen(filename[1:], shell=True, bufsize=buff,
                                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE).stdin
    elif filename.endswith('.bz2'):
        if external == NORMAL:
            import bz2
            return bz2.BZ2File(filename, mode, buff)
        elif external == PROCESS:
            if not which('bzip2'):
                return anyOpen(filename, mode, buff, NORMAL)
            if 'r' in mode:
                return anyOpen('!bzip2 -dc ' + filename, mode, buff)
            elif 'w' in mode:
                return anyOpen('!bzip2 >' + filename, mode, buff)
        elif external == PARALLEL:
            if not which('pbzip2'):
                return anyOpen(filename, mode, buff, PROCESS)
            if 'r' in mode:
                return anyOpen('!pbzip2 -dc ' + filename, mode, buff)
            elif 'w' in mode:
                return anyOpen('!pbzip2 >' + filename, mode, buff)
    elif filename.endswith('.gz'):
        if external == NORMAL:
            import gzip
            return gzip.GzipFile(filename, mode, buff)
        elif external == PROCESS:
            if not which('gzip'):
                return anyOpen(filename, mode, buff, NORMAL)
            if 'r' in mode:
                return anyOpen('!gzip -dc ' + filename, mode, buff)
            elif 'w' in mode:
                return anyOpen('!gzip >' + filename, mode, buff)
        elif external == PARALLEL:
            if not which('pigz'):
                return anyOpen(filename, mode, buff, PROCESS)
            if 'r' in mode:
                return anyOpen('!pigz -dc ' + filename, mode, buff)
            elif 'w' in mode:
                return anyOpen('!pigz >' + filename, mode, buff)
    elif filename.endswith('.xz'):
        if which('xz'):
            if 'r' in mode:
                return anyOpen('!xz -dc ' + filename, mode, buff)
            elif 'w' in mode:
                return anyOpen('!xz >' + filename, mode, buff)
    else:
        return open(filename, mode, buff)
    return None
```

The `which()` function is taken from the [Test if executable exists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377017/test-if-executable-exists-in-python) example...

A cleanup of all the many cases would be most welcome. Happy data-monkeying!

Comment: since python 3.3 xz files could be open with standard python library http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/lzma

Comment: Latest version of this solution can be found at https://github.com/DarkoVeberic/utl/tree/master/futile

Answer (score 0):

I propose a simpler solution than @Darko Vebric's. My solution uses only the python libraries, and thus do not support multithreaded decompression. If effiency is important for you, you should look to his solution. If you just need something simple and portable, I think my solution is less complex while achieving the same goal.

I have tested this with Python 3.5, but as far as I can see, the general idea should work with any Python version. You'll have to check if your version of Python supports lzma and the `with` keyword, of course.

```
import sys
import gzip
import bz2
import lzma

fn = sys.argv[1]
if fn.endswith("gz"):
    anyopen = gzip.open
elif fn.endswith("bz2"):
    anyopen = bz2.open
elif fn.endswith("xz"):
    anyopen = lzma.open
else:
    anyopen = open

with anyopen(fn) as f:
    for line in f:
         # Do something with the lines of the input file
```

Comment: Note that the python2 bz2 module has a bug and will incorrectly terminate multistream bzip2 files produced by pbzip2, see first "Note:" in https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @DarkoVeberic! Going by the docs you're safe with anything from Python 3.3. and up, and for Python 2.7 you'll have to either revert to your previously mentioned solution, or install bz2file via PyPI.