# run imposm commands from a python script

Tags: python, shell, openstreetmap, mapnik, imposm

I'm just getting started using imposm to help get openstreetmap data into a postgis database. All the docs point to making all commands via Terminal. This is fine for one off imports but I plan to have many many imports of varying bounding boxes and would like to script the loading of the data in the database.

Currently I use:

```
imposm --overwrite-cache --read --write -d postgis_test --user postgres -p ""  /Users/Me/MapnikTest/osmXML.osm
```

Which works fine from the command line but as osmXML.osm is being created many times I would like somehow to import this at the point of creation.

Putting the same thing in a python script as:

```
os.system("imposm --overwrite-cache --read --write -d postgis_test --user postgres -p ""  /Users/Ali\ Mac\ Pro/Desktop/MapnikTest/osmXML.osm")
```

just returns:

```
/bin/sh: imposm: command not found
```

Solving this would be the final step to automate the acquisition of data to render small maps on demand but I'm falling at the final hurdle!

** Edit full path to imposm solved the first problem but imputing the password for the postgres user happens when prompted. Is there a way to send the password in the same single line command? (maybe this needs to be a new post?, happy if someone points me in the right direction)**

Comment: Looks like `imposm` isn't in the PATH used by `os.system`. Type `which imposm` into the terminal for me and tell me what it says?

Comment: Actually, how are you running your script? With `python script.py` or `./script.py` or something else ... ?

Comment: `which imposm` resulted in `/usr/local/bin/imposm` - about to make a test using the full path now.

Comment: So the full path to imposm cleared up the initial problem but now the command just returns 256. I am trying this also with something simple like `os.system("/usr/local/bin/imposm --help")`, which also returns 256. I'm digging around now for those codes.

Comment: How are you running the script?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because `os.system()` is calling `/bin/sh` which uses a different shell environment from the one you use when working on the command line.

To work around this, in your script, get the full path to the `imposm` script and then use that in your command. Use can use [some code like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377017/test-if-executable-exists-in-python) to find the executable.

Or you can fix your shell definitions so that `/bin/sh` has the proper `PATH` defined, but that depends greatly on your setup...

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the help of further research and the comments from @Eli Rose (many thanks): find out what path to imposm (or whichever command you are trying to make) with

```
which <command>
```

Then include the path in the python shell command. Using a module from subprocess you can even see the full terminal output.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import *
print Popen("/usr/local/bin/imposm --overwrite-cache --read --write --connection postgis://<database user>:<password>@<host>/<database> /path/to/data.osm", stdout=PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()
```

The

```
--connection postgis://<database user>:<password>@<host>/<database>
```

means you can make the command in a single line and not have to worry about entering the database user password in a following command.