# How do I check from within python whether LaTeX and TeX Live are installed on a computer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, latex, tex

I am writing a python program which generates TeX code that gets compiled into a PDF document. For this to work, I need to make sure that the user has some distribution of LaTeX installed on their computer. How do I do this from within Python 2.7 in a platform-independent way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update for Python 3.11 and 3.12+:

According to [PEP 632](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/#migration-advice), `distutils` has been deprecated, use `shutil.which`:

```
if shutil.which('latex'): print('latex installed')
```

---

Before Python 3.10:

```
from distutils.spawn import find_executable
if find_executable('latex'): print('latex installed')
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: `distutils` is deprecated...

Comment: @DarkoVeberic I have updated the answer with a 3.12+ solution, which duplicates this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13936916/4562156