# Preview a PDF file and choose printer before actually printing the document

Tags: python, macos, printing, tkinter, printers

I am currently developing an application in Python3/tkinter that will run primarily on Macs and will need to print PDF files.

In the past, I have managed to send PDF files to printer automatically by using some commands in a bash script, so I think I could end up using that approach as a last resort.

However, I never found a way to specify one printer, it would always send it right into the currently selected printer (usually the last used one). The problem is that all those computers are connected to more that one printer, and some of the printers are not suitable for A4 documents (for instance, label printers).

Does anyone know if there is any way to launch the Preview application from command line, or any external module that allows us to preview and choose printers before actually printing?

Comment: In my Bash scripts, I use for instance `pdfsplit $FILENAME 3 |lpr` to print page 3 of a PDF file coming from the previous action. I can also specify more pages, adding their numbers with a space between each of them.

Comment: Hmm would letting the user print the pdf by themselves work as well? You could open it using [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) and let your user review and print it themselves...

Comment: @Nearoo is there a URL Scheme for the Preview app? Or would I have to launch a browser and print from there?

Comment: The latter would be the case. But I see someone already posted a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a program I've just created that allows you to select a printer and print.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import subprocess
from pprint import pprint
import platform
import sys

def which(program):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/377028/3924118
    import os
    def is_exe(fpath):
        return os.path.isfile(fpath) and os.access(fpath, os.X_OK)

    fpath, fname = os.path.split(program)
    if fpath:
        if is_exe(program):
            return program
    else:
        for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
            path = path.strip('"')
            exe_file = os.path.join(path, program)
            if is_exe(exe_file):
                return exe_file

    return None


class FilePrinterDialog(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root

        self.body = tk.Frame(self, bg="lightblue")
        self.body.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        self.title_frame = tk.Frame(self.body, pady=5)
        self.title_frame.pack(fill="both", pady=(15, 5))

        self.title = tk.Label(self.title_frame,  text="Let's print!")
        self.title.pack(fill="x")

        # Current selected printer of your system
        self.system_default_destination = self._find_system_default_destination()

        # Finds printer names
        self.printers_names = self._find_printers_names()

        self.selected_file = None  # To hold the selected file's name
        self.data_bytes = None  # Bytes read from the selected file to print
        self.selected_printer = None  # Hols name of selected printer

        # Display them
        self.printers_frame = tk.Frame(self.body, bg="lightblue", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.printers_frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        self._display_printers()

        self.bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self.body, pady=5)
        self.bottom_frame.pack(fill="both", pady=(5, 16))
        self.open_file_chooser = tk.Button(self.bottom_frame,
                                           text="Open file chooser",
                                           command=self._select_file)
        self.open_file_chooser.pack(side="left", padx=10)

        self.print_file = tk.Button(self.bottom_frame,
                                           text="Print",
                                           command=self._print_selected_file)
        self.print_file.pack(side="right", padx=10)


        self._make_modal()

    def _read_file(self):
        # NOT USED!
        if not self.selected_file:
            raise ValueError("No file chosen")
        with open(self.selected_file, "rb") as in_file: # opening for [r]eading as [b]inary
            return in_file.read() # if you only wanted to read 512 bytes, do .read(512)

    def _print_selected_file(self):
        if not self.selected_file:
            print("No file selected yet!")
        else:
            subprocess.call(["lpr", self.selected_file])

    def _select_file(self):
        self.selected_file = askopenfilename(title = "Choose file to print")
        print(self.selected_file)

    def _on_listbox_selection(self, event):
        self.selected_printer = self._find_current_selected_printer()

        # Sets the printer on your system
        subprocess.call(["lpoptions", "-d", self.selected_printer])
        print("Selected printer:", self.selected_printer)

    def _find_current_selected_printer(self):
        curselection = self.listbox.curselection()
        if len(curselection) > 0:
            return self.listbox.get(curselection[0])   
        else:
            return None

    def _display_printers(self):
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.printers_frame)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.printers_frame,
                                  yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set,
                                  selectbackground="yellow",
                                  selectmode="single",
                                  height=6)

        for printer_name in self.printers_names:
            self.listbox.insert("end", printer_name)

        # Keep track of selected listbox
        self.listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self._on_listbox_selection)

        # Sets first listbox as selected
        self.listbox.select_set(0) # Sets focus
        self.listbox.event_generate("<<ListboxSelect>>")

        self.listbox.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.listbox.yview)

    def _find_system_default_destination(self):
        return subprocess.getoutput("lpstat -d").split(": ")[1]

    def _find_printers_names(self):
        # Command to obtain printer names based on: https://superuser.com/a/1016825/317323
        return subprocess.getoutput("lpstat -a | awk '{print $1}'").split("\n")

    def _make_modal(self):
        # Makes the window modal
        self.transient(self.root)
        self.grab_set()
        self.wait_window(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not which("lpoptions") or not which("lpr") or not which("awk") or not which("lpstat"):        
        sys.stderr.write("Requirements: lopotions, lpr, lpstat and awk not satisfied")
    else:
        root = tk.Tk()
        opener = tk.Button(root, text="Open printer chooser", command=lambda: FilePrinterDialog(root))
        opener.pack()
        root.mainloop()
```

This program only works if you have the required dependencies which I specify in the program. You should have those since I'm also on a Mac OS X (Sierra).

I've tested only with a `.py` file. Unfortunately, the format of the printed documented isn't really as desired (since I'm not really an expert on how to use `lpr` to print files), but you can check the options of `lpr` and see what you can do with it.

Also, I've not created any preview of the selected file, but you may achieve this using PIL (at least for images)...

Note: be careful, do not click 100 times on the `print` button, otherwise you will have 100 files in the queue to be printed! You may want to fix this somehow.

Comment: Seems to be what I am looking for. I will study that code! :)

Comment: @VictorDomingos Nice! Make me know if there are any problems and we can eventually improve the program (maybe also for future users) ;)