# How to print a PDF in Python 3 to default printer in OSX?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, printing

I have an app that generates and prints various PDF files in windows and I'm trying to port it over to OSX. I need to print them within Python 3 to the default printer in an OSX environment. I do have some code I managed to find, but the major problem is I have to specify the printer name. I have no idea how to determine or capture that name to plug it in to the code.

```
    fn = 'path/to/file.ext'
    printer = 'ps'
    print_cmd = 'lpr -P %s %s'
    os.system(print_cmd % (printer, fn))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42786187/4602561

You can get all printers names with the following code:

```py
subprocess.getoutput("lpstat -a | awk '{print $1}'").split("\n")
```

You can also get only the default printer with the following code:

```py
subprocess.getoutput("lpstat -d").split(": ")
```